# How to edit an input value when it exceeds the limit using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<input id="myid" type="number" ng-model="maxVal" ng-change="maxValCheck()"
       max="5" min="1" value="1"/>
```

in the controller

```
$scope.maxVal;
$scope.maxValCheck = function() {
    if($scope.maxVal> 5) {
        $scope.maxVal= 5;
    }
}
```

I want to change the value of input field to 5 when it is more than 5.But it does not work. What am I doing wrong? And is there a better way you suggest to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use directive.

Example :

```
<input limit-to="5" type="number"  ng-model="maxVal" >

app.directive("limitTo", [function() { return { restrict: "A", link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitTo); angular.element(elem).on("keypress", function(e) { if (this.value > limit) e.preventDefault(); }); } } }]);
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap the `elem` argument in `angular.element`. It already is a jq-like argument.